# show GIF image in SplashScreen in Android?

Tags: android, dynamic-splash-screen

I am working to create an Splash screen, in which I have to use a GIF image.
I have already worked on the animated Splash screens in which I had used Animation API to perform animation.

Now, I have a task to work with the GIF images. Please suggest me if it is possible.???

Comment: Please look at this link - http://stackoverflow.com/a/11806460/614807